# How to insert one field of a table to another table in laravel 5?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, laravel, insert

I want to create image galleries for stuffs. So in Mysql I created two tables:

- table 1 **multiples** contained field name (id, stuff_id, images ) which **id** is *primary key* and *auto increment*, **stuff_id** is *index*.
- table 2 **stuffs** contained field name (stuff_id, name, detail) which **stuff_id** is *primary key* and *auto increment*.All I want is to upload a new stuff with 4 images,and be able to get stuff_id  in table **multiples**.

Ex: If I upload a new stuff with 4 images with **stuff_id =1** in table **multiples** should look like this::

```
|id||stuff_id||images|
|1|   |1|   |image1.jpg|
|2|   |1|   |image2.jpg|
|3|   |1|   |image3.jpg|
|4|   |1|   |image4.jpg|
```

And this is my code but it dose not do what I want (I have 2 models Stuffs and Multiple). It just insert record to tables but, in table multiples **stuff_id** it gets '**0**' 4 times.

```
public function upload_multiple(Request $request){

    $stuff = new Stuffs();
    $stuff->name = $request->input('name');
    $stuff->detail = $request->input('detail');
    $stuff->save();

    $files = $request->file('images');
    foreach ($files as $file){
    $multiple = new Multiple(); //Multiple is a 'Model' not a table name
    $destinationPath = 'uploads/';
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName(); 
    $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    $multiple->images =$destinationPath.$filename;
    $multiple->save();
}
```

So how can I do this in Laravel 5? 
Many thank for help!

Comment: that why I asked for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a [One to Many relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#one-to-many). Here's how you can set it up:

In your Model classes, add the following:

```
class Stuffs {
    ...
    // A Stuff has many Mutliples
    public function multiples() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Multiple');
    }

}

class Multiple {
    ...
    // A Multiple belongs to only one Stuff
    public function stuff() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Stuffs');
    }
}
```

Then, while adding a Stuff, you can simply [attach Multiples to it](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models):

```
public function upload_multiple(Request $request) {
    $stuff = new Stuffs();
    $stuff->name = $request->input('name');
    $stuff->detail = $request->input('detail');
    $stuff->save();

    $files = $request->file('images');

    $multiples = [];

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $multiple = new Multiple(); //Multiple is a 'Model' not a table name
        ...

        $multiples[] = $multiple;
    }

    $stuff->multiples()->saveMany($multiples);
}
```

Comment: I got this error:: Method name must be a string @John Bupit

Comment: I don't understand about $multiples = []; and $multiples[] = $multiple; should I place some value

Comment: `$multiples = []` is equivalent to `$multiples = array()`, i.e. defining a new array. `$multiples[] = $multiple` means you're pushing `$multiple` to the `$multiples` array, [as explained in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

Comment: Do I need to add this two lines of code to my code?

Comment: Yes. `$stuff->multiples()-saveMany($multiples)` means that you're attaching an array of `Multiple` objects to `$stuff`. Those 2 lines I added, create the `$multiples` array.

Comment: Thanks you! you helped me alot(:(:(:   @John Bupit

Comment: Unknown column 'stuffs_id'. But in Mysql field is stuff_id. I wonder wthat's wrong?

Comment: [According to the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#one-to-many), the default foreign key Eloquent will take is your model name followed by an underscore and `id`. Since your model name is `Stuffs`, it is taking `stuffs_id` by default. You can always change the default behavior by specifying the foreign key field name as the second argument of the `hasMany()` function: `return $this->hasMany('App\Multiple', 'stuff_id')`.

Comment: Unknown column 'stuff_id' :( very headache now, one error pass one error comes.Very Dizzy:(:(

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? I would really recommend you rename your model to `Stuff`, as that follows the Laravel's naming conventions.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stuff_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `multiples` (`images`, `stuff_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (uploads/Dell_XPS_11_2-800x800.jpg, 16, 2015-07-20 09:36:19, 2015-07-20 09:36:19))

Comment: Check your schema for multiples table. What all fields does it have? Did you run your database migrations correctly?

Comment: Can you please show me how to join that two tables to get records back? I don't know how to deal with this?